# How to get the distinct values of a range with two criteria in Excel with formula or VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, count, unique

I have a column with around 16k rows with duplicate dates in which should be searched for the Count of Unique dates between a week. Here [image: SHEET WMR in the code]is the sheet where the unique counts should be stored in row DAYS #8 and above it are the dates that should be used as conditions. I have tried Sum/countifs array formula but i got Division with 0 Error. Then I tried this loop

```
Dim WMR, MHR, P, D As Worksheet

Set WMR = Sheets("WMREP")
Set MHR = Sheets("MACH-HRS")
Set P = Sheets("PRODUCTION")
Set D = Sheets("DELAYS")

Dim last_row, last_row1, last_row2 As Long
last_row = MHR.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last_row1 = P.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last_row2 = D.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
counter = 1

For x = 8 To 11
    For y = 3 To last_row1
        If P.Cells(y, 1) >= WMR.Cells(7, x - 1) And P.Cells(y, 1) < WMR.Cells(7, x) Then
            If P.Cells(y, 1) <> P.Cells(y - 1, 1) Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next y
    WMR.Cells(8, x) = counter
    counter = 0
Next x
```

But it returns values more than 7 and it is not right. I am stuck with this one. Formula or VBA solution would be appreciated.

[image: Sheet P in the code]

Comment: First up would be a small slice of data (sample) to work with, and show us what your expected result would be on that sample data. It's much easier to come up with a sollution when we see what you are actually working with

Comment: I am unfimilliar with dictionaries. And this one is urgent, so I would go with something that I understand or works. The only part that is not visible is the column with the dates. Which is very straightforward, the name of the column in the first row and dates afterwards.

Comment: Right, so you want to count unique days that fall within 30-dec upto 05-jan? It's also relevant to know if you have access to the newer dynamic array formulas.

Comment: Here is some of it, it it helps. I have edited the post. Yes, exactly! I am not sure about that..

Comment: And do you have access to dynamic array formulas? for example `UNIQUE` function?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I have looked in the formulas and this one does not appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you had access to DA-functions, it would be rather easy:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!$A2:$A16000,Sheet2!$A2:$A16000>G7-1,Sheet2!$A2:$A16000<G7+7)))
```

But not having access to those, you could try:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((Sheet2!$A2:$A16000>G7-1)*(Sheet2!$A2:$A16000<G7+7),Sheet2!$A2:$A16000),Sheet2!$A2:$A16000)>0))
```

**Note:** This second option needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. Both options can be put in `G7` on Sheet1 and be dragged to the right.

Know, that if needed, you can also make the reference to column A dynamic so you won't have to hardcode rows.

Comment: The scariest formula I have seen in Excel. But it worked! However, can I ask you how would the same formula look like if it was for months? Considering that the month is not always 30 days..

Comment: Glad it worked. New questions get new topics =). I don't mean to be rude, but it's simply better to formulate a better new question with sample data then to continue back and forth using comments @LBD_23.